# TypeScript: how to optimize compile-bundle-reload cycle?

Tags: typescript, webpack, bundling-and-minification, web-frontend

I just set up a trivial TypeScript project with React & Webpack and the edit-build-reload-test cycle isn't ideal since I have to

1. Rebuild manually with `npm run build:dev`
2. Wait 9 seconds for `tsc && webpack app.js -o app.bundle.js --mode=development`
3. Refresh the browser.

Fellow coders, what techniques do you use to get a faster workflow? (non-webpack solutions welcome!)

Comment: You want to use `webpack-dev-server` and `ts-loader`, then you have a single process watching for changes and live-reloading a browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out about [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/). It is by far the easiest way to get a fast workflow...

[image]

Just add a `<script src="app.tsx"></script>` reference to your html file and then run `parcel index.html` (or whatever). Parcel

1. Checks if you have a package.json and if not, creates one for you
2. Installs TypeScript (with `--save-dev`) if that's the language you're using
3. Installs React or Preact if you imported one of those
4. Creates a bundle of your app with its dependencies in a `dist` folder
5. Serves your app at http://localhost:1234
6. Watches for code changes and recompiles (in less than 200ms for a tiny app)
7. Pushes changes out to the web browser automatically with Hot Module Replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader) (or [awesome-typescript-loader](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader)) to allow webpack process your typescript files.

Also, webpack can be run with `--watch` option, which allows webpack to watch for files changes and rebuild bundle automatically

> webpack can watch files and recompile whenever they change.

In this case your build:dev script would be `webpack app.js -o app.bundle.js --mode=development --watch` (without running tsc)

PS. you can also faster the refreshing phase by enabling [Hot Module Replacement](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/) so you don't need to reload the page manually (it can even preserve the state), but it would require some changes in the codebase (for react, [react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader) is recommended), though it would additionally require to use `babel-loader` in your webpack config.